# Monitoring heroku instances' workload

Tags: heroku

What's the best way to monitor your heroku instances' workloads (besides `top`), so you know when to scale? I'd rather not use an auto-scaling program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of tailing the heroku logs (possibly using one of the logging addons like Papertrail or Loggly) and New Relic.

Comment: Will check out New Relic. In the logs, I assume you mean keeping an eye on `queue=x wait=XXms service=XXms`. Is there anything else you monitor in the logs, besides the load times for the specific resources? And do you have any rules of thumb (specific or relative figures for queue=, etc...) that you use?

Comment: There's no golden rules but if you have a sustained figure for queue then you need to add more dynos as the current level can't process the requests fast enough.